# Confluent Kafka dot net ProduceAsync tasks

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

```
var msgs = new List<string> {“msg1”, “msg2”, “msg3”};

var tasks = new List<Task>();

Foreach(var msg in msgs) {
         tasks.add(_producer.ProduceAsync(...)); }

var deliveryReports = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
```

My Kafka producer config:

Batch size: 10
Linger:100 ms

My question is, do the tasks get completed in the order they were
 created. Can I guarantee that the task representing msg1 completes
 before the task representing msg2 or msg3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I now understand how the producer and the broker works to achieve ordering.

So, when ProduceAsync is called, it adds the message to the send buffer, creates promise that is used to complete future and returns future.So, it creates task completion source object and returns its task.

The client library(librdkafka) waits until it receives the configured number of messages or timeout period to batch the messages. A batch is created containing the messages in the same order as in the send buffer. The batch is partitioned (randomly if the default partitioner is used) based on their destination partitions/topics, i.e. split into smaller batches. Each post-split batch is sent to the respective leader broker/ISR (the individual send()’s happen sequentially), and each is acked by its respective leader broker according to request.required.acks. The client library invokes a callback on each ack it receives and the callback completes its respective future i.e taskCompletionSource.Set();

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things here.

First, librdkafka has the capability to manage re-tries for you and by default it does ('retries' is set to 2) - so this can cause re-ordering of message delivery and delivery reports. To ensure this doesn't happen you can set 'max.in.flight' to 1 (or 'retries' to 0 and manage this yourself).

With librdkafka configured to supply delivery-reports back to .net in the order the messages are sent, the question becomes one of Task completion ordering guarantees. I need to think about this for more than 5 minutes to give a good answer, but for now assume ordering is not guaranteed (I will write more later). You can get guaranteed ordering by using the variants of ProduceAsync that accept an IDeliveryReport handler. Note that in version 1.0, these methods will be changed somewhat and will be called BeginProduce.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm not really worried about re-tries and delivery reports because like you said I can disable the retries and am not really concerned about order of delivery reports. I'm only concerned about the order the messages are sent. The kafka client library maintains a queue, yeah? How does it despatch items in the queue? Will it maintain the order when it creates a MessageEnvelope (containg msg1, msg2, msg3)? Thanks.